# Contenteditable <summary> tag

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Okay, here's the situation:

I have a `<details>` tag and I want to make its `<summary>` tag `contenteditable` at some point during the program. The problem is, when I have an editable summary, I can't use the space key because the space by default opens and closes the details tag. Here's an example:

```html
<details>
  <summary contenteditable>Edit me!</summary>
  <p>Some content here</p>
</details>
```

I can't use `event.preventDefault()` because that would also prevent the space from being typed. Is there some way, with JS or HTML, that I can allow the user to add a space when editing the summary tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tough luck. But one thing I did get working is to `.preventDefault()` and manually insert a space using `execCommand()` or `insertNode()`: https://jsbin.com/yoxuwos/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I was wondering if something like that was possible!